# When a subclass overrides a method, how can we ensure at compile time that the superclass's method implementation is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The classic example is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; // Subclasses sometimes forget this line

    // Subclass's implementation goes here
}
```

What are some ways to ensure at compile time that `UIViewController` subclasses always call `[super viewDidLoad]` when they override `[UIViewController viewDidLoad]`?

Comment: Write the code correctly.  (I don't know, does Analyzer check this sort of thing?)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If we're talking about custom classes, you can add the following to your superclass's method declaration:

```
__attribute__((objc_requires_super));
```

---

And if you want to ensure that all of your `UIViewController` subclasses call a method like `[super viewDidLoad];`,  you could subclass `UIViewController` something like this:

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad __attribute__((objc_requires_super));

// per Scott's excellent comment:
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;

@end
```

---

```
@implementation BaseViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

@end
```

And then just subclass `BaseViewController` throughout your project, rather than subclassing `UIViewController`.

Any subclass of `BaseViewController` which implements `viewDidLoad` and does not call `[super viewDidLoad];` (which in turn calls `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`) will throw a warning.

---

EDIT: I've edited the answer to include an example of `NS_REQUIRES_SUPER`, per Scott's excellent comment.  The two examples (`viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear:`) are functionally equivalent.  Though I imagine `NS_REQUIRES_SUPER` probably will autocomplete for you.  I'll likely begin using this macro myself in the future.

Comment: There's also a little easier to remember macro: `NS_REQUIRES_SUPER`.

Comment: is there a swift version for this?

Comment: @Jacky unfortunately, no, as far as I've been able to tell. But the `override` keyword is helpful in Swift