# Objective-c: Write private methods with small chance of being overridden

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say I've got a UIView subclass I often follow this pattern

```
@implementation Unicorn

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup
{
    // Important initial setup
    // This view will fall down and break hard on you if this code never runs
    // 
    // This is just an example of a *private* method though the 
    // nature of this specific method implies *protected* 
    // (nonetheless: for sake of discussion regard it as a private method)
}

@end
```

Another dev comes by and wants to subclass `Unicorn` with his new class `LaserUnicorn`. It is both likely and possible that this method `-setup`-method will be overridden.

There are various reasons why this is likely

- the subclass-dev by coincidence follows the same pattern and doesn't check against the base-class
- the base-class is refactored / changed at a later time (after subclassing) and the base-class-dev didn't have access to check all subclasses
- the base-class implementation is within a library/framework/api (the subclass-dev does not have insight in the implementation of the class)

**Q:** Couldn't this be solved by prefixing every private method with `_` underscore?
**A:** If that's the custom it could very likely be the custom for the `LaserUnicorn` as well.

**Q:** Okay, what about renaming the `-[Unicorn setup]` method to `-[Unicorn setupUnicorn]` and then it wouldn't matter if the LaserUnicorn-class named it `-[LaserUnicorn setup]` or `-[LaserUnicorn setupLaserUnicorn]`?
**A:** Okay, what about all the other private methods? Should we really suffix everything with the class-name just because it is private? Remember most methods *are* or *should* actually be private so that the header is left with a clean, small and understandable interface.

**Q:** But is this really a problem? I get your theory, but when does this ever happen?
**A:** For me this is one of the everyday struggles where uncertainty sneaks in on me. I don't like uncertainty. At least not when it influences how I name methods in case someone subclasses my class.

**Q:** I'm out for words. Is there anything we can do?
**A:** It's a cold world brother. This is a bigger problem when it comes to categories. There we *must* suffix everything. At least with the shift towards increasingly creating and using more and more different pods and libraries.

So what I'm looking for is good solutions to this everyday-problem. Are there any recommendations from Apple on this topic?

Comment: Honestly I don't understand the problem. Where do those questions and answers come from?

Comment: @Merlevede I made them :D `-setup` is just one example. Why don't you think this is a problem?

Comment: If  the problem is that the super class's methods should always be called because it is important that their logic is always executed, then this is your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446018/when-a-subclass-overrides-a-method-how-can-we-ensure-at-compile-time-that-the-s/21446076#21446076

Comment: @nhgrif That only applies to public methods, right? Good to know though.

Comment: Well, method overriding is one of the great features of OOP. Anyone wanting to subclass a class must understand what the base class does, (through documentation or code analysis). If someone is overriding -setup: they must understand the base implementation.

Comment: Or protected methods.  But `LaserUnicorn` can't call `Unicorn`'s private methods except through a public `Unicorn` method that calls that private method.  In which case, these public methods should require super.

Comment: @nhgrif I've made an answer based on your comment. `-setup` is a method very likely to be of the protected-kind. But what about private methods?

Comment: @Merlevede Well, what if: the base-class is refactored / changed at a later time (after subclassing) and the base-class-dev didn't have access to check all subclasses? Or the base-class implementation is within a library/framework/api (the subclass-dev does not have insight in the implementation of the class)?

Comment: Unless you're the sole user of those classes, refactoring the base class is something you just don't do (except bug fixes, or 'enhance the algorithm'). When a method's implementation is not useful anymore the right thing to do is deprecate it and creating a new one with another name (imagine if Apple changed the implementation of their objects without letting us know!!!), regardless if it's a library or not.

Comment: @Merlevede Well, I think you just stated this is something to be concerned about. So I don't get why people downvote this question. Anyways, good point! But won't this lead to code-rot? Maintaining stuff just in case seems like another uncertainty to annoy me. :)

Comment: Wait hang on... I was trying to come up with a solution for your refactoring... but that's not really necessary.  If the super class is refactored and it has too many subclasses to check them all, it should be done so in a way that requires no changes in the subclasses.

Comment: @hfossli Code-rot is a whole different topic, but maintaining stuff is just part of software's life-cycle, and this changes dramatically from project to project.

Comment: I think you two sum it up all quite nice. It would be great to have this as an answer instead of comments, then I could accept it for future readers.

Comment: anyway, I find it valid. other languages cope with it by giving the ability to mark stuff private or final or whatever

Comment: @Daij-Djan What do you find valid? The question or the answers in the comment?

Comment: thee question. not everything is meant to be subclassed

Answer (score 1):

Based on @nhgrif's comment.

Write out every protected method in a interface with `NS_REQUIRES_SUPER`. E.g.:

```
@interface Unicorn (SubclassEyesOnly)

- (void)setup NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;

@end
```

Comment: No probs, though it doesn't work by enforcing anything it is completely valid, right?

Comment: I wouldn't do that since that implies it should/can  be overriden

Comment: +1. Overriding `-setup` is fine in the original example so long as the subclasser calls super. This should probably be in the main header to ensure that subclassers always see it declared as NS_REQUIRES_SUPER though.

Comment: I disagree  since setup is only meant as an example  of a method you shouldn't subclass

Answer (score 1):

Now I expect downvotes!! :D I'm thinking outside the box here.

```
#define PRIVATE(NAME) UNICORN__##NAME

@implementation Unicorn

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self PRIVATE(setup)];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
        [self PRIVATE(setup)];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)PRIVATE(setup)
{
    // throwing in an awful example for method with parameters
    [self PRIVATE(moveLeg:)UnicornLegFrontLeft forward:YES];

    // which is the equivalent of doing
    [self UNICORN__moveLeg:UnicornLegFrontRight forward:YES];
}

- (void)PRIVATE(moveLeg:)(UnicornLeg)leg forward:(BOOL)forward
{
}

@end
```

Now while this is hands down **ugly** it would certainly make it impossible to override methods by accident!

Comment: +1 for out-of-the-box :D -- I don't think I would  do this but it does indeed render accidental overriding a rare thing

Answer (score 1):

two thing you can do with objC.. well it bores down to ONE:

1. prefix the method names to avoid accidental override (don't use _ or __)
2. dont expose the methods in the header!

=> bores down to:

**HIDE the method**

Comment: I said DONT use _ ;) I said PREFIX methods if you really wanna hide them

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that prefixing with underscore, private methods in classes that are meant to be overridden is the best thing you can do.

> Q: Couldn't this be solved by prefixing every private method with _ underscore?
>   
> A: If that's the custom it could very likely be the custom
>   for the LaserUnicorn as well.

If `LaserUnicorn` is meant to be subclassed, then it would make sense to use an underscore too. Otherwise no need to, that's what the `setup` method below is meant to do.

In your .h file:

```
@interface Unicorn : UIView

- (void)setup; // Override in subclasses

@end
```

In your .m file:

```
@implementation Unicorn

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self _setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
        [self _setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)_setup
{
    // Important initial setup
    // This view will fall down and break hard on you 
    // if this code never runs

    [self setup];
}

- (void)setup {} // Override in subclasses

@end
```

No need for `[super setup]`. Plus, you reduce your chances to override your method by accident.

Comment: Now this makes perfect sense given that you want to facilitate for every subclass the `-setup`-method. Then one might as well just do http://stackoverflow.com/a/21798495/202451

Comment: I guess that's up to you and your own coding guidelines.

Answer (score -1):

Be pragmatic and only name the methods you think is likely that someone else overrides by accident. Rename `-[Unicorn setup]` to `-[Unicorn setupUnicorn]`.

Answer (score -1):

For every level you subclass add one `_` to every private method.

If you inherit directly from NSObject you use 1 underscore (`_`). If you inherit from someone inheriting from NSObject you add an extra underscore (`__`).

Not perfect, but would be quite simple.