# How to detect which view is appeared without modifying the code in ViewControllers but only AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen, detection

Is there a way to accomplish this? Like let's say a framework perhaps?

All I need is something like:

```
aViewController appeared
bTableViewController appeared
cViewController appeared
```

Like I added a code in each `viewDidLoad`, but without adding that code. I know that there is a `visibleViewController` if I used navigation embed but I don't and I can't.

The framework I'm working on is based on no baseline, so I can not assume anything, like I'll past a code in a project and when the user compiles the code, I will get the views.

The purpose is I'm creating an analytic tool without being have to add individual code in each view controllers's `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: what's the purpose? can you explain it better

Comment: @Retro added my purpose

Comment: You could subclass either UINavigationController, UITableBarController etc and add your analytics code every time the push or change time action occurs by overriding the methods and adding your code before calling the super class.

Comment: @Pete42 if i override default files of apple given classes, wouldn't a third person have to get my own type of that class?IF yes, that defeats my purpose

Comment: @Pete42 and what if the user's application is not even a navigation or tab but simple modal based segue

Comment: Well without adding any code the view controllers I dont see how this would be possible. You will need to get some sort of reference to the controllers by either adding code to the controller or by keeping track of all controllers through the navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's no such thing as a "visible view controller" technically speaking, despite the annoyingly named method of navigation controllers.  Instead, we should be talking about visible views.  There's nothing visible about the controller.

But what you really want to know is what view controller is active and controlling visible views.  With a navigation controller, it's the top of the nav-stack, with a tab bar controller, it's the selected view controller, etc.

By implementing ONLY code in app-delegate, I don't know of any way to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.

Instead, what would be your best option would be to provide a framework that included a subclass of `UIViewController` and `UIAppDelegate`.

Set the code in these to do all the analytical work necessary.  Provide this framework as a whole and inform your users that if they want to make use of the analytics you've provide, they'll need to subclass your view controller instead of `UIViewController`, etc.

In your custom classes, just override `viewDidAppear:` to send a notification and `viewDidDisappear:` to send a notification.  And the appdelegate just manages an array that keeps track of which is on top, adding when the `viewDidAppear:` notification fires, and removing when the `viewDidDisappear:` notification fires.

And to be sure your `viewDidAppear:`/`viewDidDisappear:` isn't overridden, be sure to make use of this: [When a subclass overrides a method, how can we ensure at compile time that the superclass's method implementation is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446018/when-a-subclass-overrides-a-method-how-can-we-ensure-at-compile-time-that-the-s/21446076#21446076)

---

So in your view controller base class, it'd be as simple as posting a notification:

```
// AnalyticViewController.h

@interface AnalyticViewController : UIViewController
- (void)viewDidAppear NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewDidDisappear NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
@end

// AnalyticViewController.m

@implementation AnalyticViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AnalyticVCAppeared"
                                                        object:self
                                                      userInfo:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AnalyticVCDisappeared"
                                                        object:self
                                                      userInfo:nil];
}

@end
```

And register for these in the App delegate in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.  You'll want an mutable array to keep track of the stack of view controllers.  And you'll want separate methods for each notification.

Given a property `@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *analyzedViewControllers;`, the methods that respond to the notifications should look like this:

```
- (void)handleViewAppear:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    if (!self.analyzedViewControllers) {
        self.analyzedViewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    [self.analyzedViewControllers addObject:[aNotification object]];
}

- (void)handleViewDisappeared:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self.analyzedViewControllers removeObject:[aNotification object]];
}
```

And the top-most view controller will always be at `[self.analyzedViewControllers lastObject]`.

---

If you need to send more information about the view controller, you can using the `userInfo` argument when posting the notification.  You could even put the entire notification into the array, so you have the view controller reference and the user info reference.

What can also be important to note however is that just because one view controller has appeared doesn't inherently mean another has disappeared.  View controllers don't necessarily take up the entire screen, and although there's eventually a practical limit to how many view controllers have visible views on screen, it's a quite high limit.

---

**ADDENDUM:** To add some clarity... in the `AnalyticViewController` class I'm recommending, we have this line:

```
@interface AnalyticViewController : UIViewController
```

A line similar to this exists in every one of your view controller's header files.  What I'm recommending is that all your other view controllers subclass this one, so instead of:

```
@interface FooBarViewController : UIViewController
```

You'd instead have this:

```
#import AnalyticViewController.h
@interface FooBarViewController : AnalyticViewController
```

And the code in the `viewDidAppear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` of `AnalyticViewController` is now automatically in `FooBarViewController` unless you ignore the `NS_REQUIRES_SUPER` warning and override the `viewDidAppear:` or `viewDidDisappear:` methods.

It will be a little bit of effort to change over existing view controllers, but for any future view controllers that are not yet created, it's as simple as choosing to subclass `AnalyticViewController` rather than `UIViewController` when you create the file.

Comment: well, first of all, thanks for this elaborate explanation, but as i wrote in the question, i already have a framework for several things to do.Isnt this method would require me to copy paste those little code fragments in each viewController?

Thats what i was trying to avoid.

Comment: No.  You write a new class called `AnalyticViewController` or whatever, which is a subclass of `UIViewController`.  Now change all your view controllers to be a subclass of `AnalyticViewController` and any new view controllers you create should subclass `AnalyticViewController` instead of `UIViewController`.

Comment: One great advantage to this is that if you want a view controller omitted from the analysis, for whatever reason, it's as simple as leaving it as a `UIViewController` subclass instead of an `AnalyticViewController` subclass.

Comment: will it support tableViewControllers and others controllers aswell?Thank you so much for your effort on this btw

Comment: It won't support table view controllers, but you'd just have to create a `AnalyticTableViewController` and copy & paste the `@implementation` for `AnalyticViewController` into it.  It won't work for tabbar or nav controllers, but it doesn't need to.  The controllers embedded in these controllers will post notifications.

Comment: And if you need to know whether or not a view controller is embedded in a tabbar or navbar, it's better to ask the view controller (it'll have a reference to tabbar/navbar it's embedded in).

Answer (score -1):

For creating a analytical framework i would say you should write a kinda protocol of a rootviewController and viewController class and that delegate methods can be implemented in app delegate for knowing and handling your purpose.

Comment: How would this help even remotely?  Give an example of a protocol you could write allowing view controllers to conform to it that would let the app delegate know which one is active.

Comment: and how do i proceed on that, can you point me in the right direction with documentations etc.

Comment: @nhgrif can you help me on this subject, if you have any other idea

Comment: it's like testFlight, they handle there webservices get called from there sdk for there check points

Comment: How is that related @Retro?  Provide an example of doing what THIS question asks in the way you suggest.

Comment: All a protocol will do is allow the app delegate to know what methods it could call on view controllers that conform to that protocol.  It doesn't give it any clue as to when it should call those methods or on which view controller to call the methods on.

Comment: but a protocol can tell that what appear as he wanted i guess, even which controller get called. but i haven't tried but i am sure this could be achieve

Comment: No, it can't.  A protocol can't do this without writing code in the view controllers themselves... if you're so certain, then prove me wrong with an example in your answer, and I'll change my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: yeah, you are right, it's not possible. Thanks for correcting me.