# in swift, any way to enforce super.methodname is called?

Tags: ios, swift, subclass

Lets say I have a baseclass with some function named `testFunction`.  I am inheriting from my baseclass into a few different subclasses.  they override `testFunction`, but I want to enforce them calling `super.testFunction()`.   Is there any way to make this mandatory?

Comment: The objective-c compiler will warn you about certain methods not calling super, so it seems likely there's a way, but it's not clear at all that it's: a) accessible in swift, or b) user definable and not just part of the compiler.

Comment: Yeah exactly.. thats why I was wondering about that.  I would really like my app not to compile, or at least throw a fatal error if I forget to implement superclass methods.

Comment: In Objective-C it is user-definable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446018/when-a-subclass-overrides-a-method-how-can-we-ensure-at-compile-time-that-the-s/21446076#21446076 but Swift does not fully support preprocessor statements.

Comment: ah, that really sucks.  would be nice to have

Comment: Note that this doesn't make it mandatory. The code would compile with warnings. And I don't know if it still generates a warning in Swift if you subclass an Objective-C class that used that technique. Swift is also different in that you get an error if you don't specify the override keyword, which Objective-C doesn't do.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this way:

```
class A {
    final func testFunction() {
        // do some required stuff
        optionalFunction()
    }

    func optionalFunction() {
        // you can override this in subclasses
    }
}

class B: A {
    override func optionalFunction() {

    }
}
```

So subclasses can not override `testFunction` and should override `optionalFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

*I will admit that I didn't look this up first, so it could be slightly incorrect.*

This isn't possible. `init` is a special case that the compiler looks for and has specific wording indicating that:

> Super.init isn't called before returning from initializer

What you *could* do is declare your method as `final` and then have another overridable method. Not only does this ensure your original method is called, but it also (mostly) guarantees that you have control over the order of operations.

```
final func testFunction() {
  // do stuff
  otherFunction()
  // do more stuff
}

func otherFunction() {
  fatalError("Must Override")
}
```